# Editing ArcSDE Oracle spatial view

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, oracle-spatial, spatial-view

Can you edit an ArcSDE Oracle spatial view?

By 'edit' I mean edit the geometry in the feature class, not any attributes in the joined table. Unversioned.

I really had it in my head that you can, as long as the objectid column is included in the view along with the shape column, some half-remembered reference. So I was forging ahead and decided to double-check if there was fine print, and now it seems I was whackadoodle in the first place.

I've seen nothing to suggest it is supported, and seen in [Administering ArcSDE for Oracle](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/geodatabase/pdf/oracle.pdf), page 225: "Spatial
views cannot be edited through an ArcSDE client."

But then I went ahead and tried it today, and I could edit a spatial view in ArcMap, but given the above I question how safe it is.

Answer (score 3):

Native RDBMS views should probably not be edited. I have never edited one in ArcMap, just with SQL so I haven't edited geometry. I've done attribute updates in the past but it is dangerous because the view is unaware of the A & D tables, assuming your data is versioned. insert and delete operations can really get you into trouble.

If the data is versioned can you use a [(multi)versioned](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z0000000q000000) view instead?

Comment: unversioned, so no A and D table complications.